# Command that helps link programs?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, stdout, stdin

Sorry if this title is confusing I'm not exactly sure how to word this, I wrote these two C programs explained here successfully:
[image]

but when I go to test them like my professor told us to I get `readin: Command not found` and `writeout: Command not found` which makes sense because normally after I compile (with GCC) I would run the program with ./ and then the name of the program. I'm confused as to what he meant and if there is some sort of command that would make this work? Unfortunately my professor is offline and I haven't been able to find anything on the web about it. On a linux operating system and compiled both programs using gcc -std=c99. Any help is greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: It is a problem of your environment variable. it has nothing to do with your C programs. your shell will not search the current path for executables. To fix it, run this `expose PATH=.:$PATH` in your shell, then you can run `readbin`

Comment: If readin and writeout do exist in the current folder, then you could just change the command-line to `./readin in.txt | ./writeout out.txt`

Comment: @stensal thanks for the reply, when I ran that I get "expose: Command not found" as well. I am ssh'ing to my school computer and running these commands there which is linux OS if that info helps any.

Comment: @GemTaylor That's what I though too but tried that and it crashed my terminal lol

Comment: That probably indicates that there are bugs to that effect in the programs readin and writeout programs. If you run readin on its own, then I expect it will print to the console.
You can run writeout on its own, by using similar redirection `echo hello world|writeout test.txt`

Comment: it should be  `export` not `expose`, my fault.

Comment: @GemTaylor Yes was able to test readin and it prints out exactly what is in the txt file given on the command line. When I try the echo command I still get writeout: Command not found

Comment: Perhaps I had more issues than I thought, I attached a screenshot of my terminal session to my question, it is not recognizing these commands

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if the current directory `.` is included in your `$PATH` environment variable.

Comment: Ok thanks, running from the current directory that has all the files and for all of our programs we haven't had to mess with an environment variables but maybe he just forgot to mention it, I'll look into thanks for the info

Comment: Do not put `.` in your executable search path. This is a security hazard: If an attacker can get a script or program into a directory you use, and can choose a name for it that is the name of some common command (e.g., by offering a ZIP archive you unpack), then you may inadvertently execute their program instead of the intended command. Then the program will run with your permissions and can do malicious things. Instead, simply modify the teacher’s instructions: Run the programs using `./name` instead of `name`. (Also, if your instructor has `.` in their path, tell them I said to stop it.)

Comment: Ok good to know maybe that's why we are not allowed to modify the path haha, we normally run our programs with ./ not sure why he suggested different this time. Nonetheless thank you for the reply I did not know that.